# Prove that: $\frac{d}{dt} f(x + tu) \mid_{t=0} = \langle \nabla f(x), u \rangle$ and another question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I encountered this in the solution of some exercise in Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class. The claim is that for a differentiable function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(x + tu) \mid_{t=0} = \langle \nabla f(x), u \rangle$$

What is the definition of differentiability for a function of several variables? Why does that equality hold? And what is the general formula which produces this particular result?

Thank you.

Comment: For fixed $x, u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(x + tu)$ is a function of one variable, $t$, so one can take its derivative with respect to $t$.

Comment: It depends on how you defined $\nabla f$. If is defined as the vector the components of which are the partial derivatives of $f$, then Umberto P. s answer shows how to see this. If you defined it as the unique vector with the property $df  (v) = \langle \nabla f, v\rangle $ for all $v$ then SpamIAms comment is easier to follow. In any case, both are equivalent of course.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x(t) = x + t u = (x_1+tu_1,\ldots x_n+tu_n)$ and 
Apply the chain rule: $$\frac d{dt} f(x(t)) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} f(x(t)) \frac{d}{dt}(x_k + t u_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} f(x(t))u_k = \nabla f(x+tu) \cdot u.$$

Comment: Why do we take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x_k$ instead of $x_k+tu_k$ or $u_k$?